# execute MS Access SQL in MFC, regex * is ignored

Tags: ms-access

I want to get all the use tables.

```
SELECT name FROM MSYSOBJECTS WHERE TYPE=1 AND NAME NOT LIKE 'MSys*'
```

That is ok directly execution in access.
But When it's in MFC code

```
m_pRecordset->Open("SELECT name FROM MSYSOBJECTS WHERE TYPE=1 AND NAME NOT LIKE 'MSys*'", m_pConnection.GetInterfacePtr(), adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText);
```

There are tables
MSysObjects MSysACEs MSysQueries MSysRelationships
included.

Why?

/*****************************************************/

I've already got the answer

```
SELECT name FROM MSYSOBJECTS WHERE TYPE=1 AND NAME NOT LIKE 'MSys%'
```

Answer (score -1):

I've already got the answer

```
SELECT name FROM MSYSOBJECTS WHERE TYPE=1 AND NAME NOT LIKE 'MSys%'
```